# onclick function executes without any click on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, dom-events

I am working with some JavaScript and Ajax functions. I am going to put some code while I explain myself to be more clear.

I have this element: `<div id="divTest" onclick="test()">YES</div>`

When the user clicks the DIV, the function replaces the "YES" for something like this:

```
YES <input type="radio" name="testing" value="YES" onclick="test_2(this.value)" checked /> 
NO <input type="radio" name="testing" value="NO" onclick="test_2(this.value)" />
```

This allows the user to select again the right option. Then I want to replace the radiobuttons with new value, so when the user selects any option, the DIV replaces the "radio" options and displays the value selected (YES OR NO) as it was on the beginning.

At this point everything works perfect.

Here is my problem:

I want the DIV to have the `onclick()` as the beginning `onclick="test()"` so I do it from JavaScript giving it the property this way: `div.onclick = function() { test();};`. The function `test()` is executed even if the user does not click on the div. It executes both function right away and does not wait until there is a click on it.

Does anyone knows how can I make the function to wait until there is any click on it? Am I giving the `onclick` property incorrectly?

I hope I made myself clear.

Here are the functions:

```
function test() {
   var div = document.getElementById("divTest");
   //I DO NOT INCLUDE THE AJAX CODE BUT THE RESPONSE INCLUDE THE RADIO BUTTONS METIONED ABOVE
   div.innerHTML = xml.responseText();
}

function test_2(newValue) {
   div = document.getElementById("newValue");
   div.innerHTML = newValue;
   div.onclick = function() { test(); };
}
```

Comment: Can you put a demo up on http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your problem is with `div.onclick =` here you are actually assigning a click action to your div! Which will execute when your page loads.

What you want is to assign an event listener like so.

```
div.addEventListener('click' function(){});
```

Comment: @mauguerra then your going to have to post a jsfiddle like Jonathan said. Because something is off in your code. The above should work.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem and I found this page. I check the spec of addEventListener and I found out I typed an excessive pair of bracket.

Two ways to do this: 
1.use anonymous function(that is without a name, defined just in time to use) like the above answer.
2. you can't add the bracket. simply use ('click', myfunction).

If you want to use parameter, wrap your function into an anonymous function. like this:
div.addEventListener('click', function(){myfunction(e){}}).

it's a little bit late, hope you can read it and solve your problem.

Comment: I have edited the formatting and wording of your answer. I think your last code bit is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: First time answering questions. Thanks, and the parenthesis has been added

Comment: I was editing at the same time you were editing. So when I was done, I saw your comment, I found out mine overrided yours. I am willing to accept your formatting